# Hibernate lazy loading with repeated data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two tables `employee` and `bankname`. In employee table there is a column `bank_name_id` which refers the column of bank table.

I have mapped employee `bank_name_id` with bank `bank_name_id` with many to one

I'm using spring mvc `@RestController` while returning it correctly fetch the data from bankname but converting into json its have repeated fetched data

```
Table 1    Employee Table:
empid empname bank_name_id
1     XXX      1

Table 2    Bankname table
bank_name_id bank_name
1             QQQ
```

JSON output:

```
{
    empid:1,
    empname:"xxx",
    bank:{bank_name_id:1,bank_name:QQQ},
    bankname:{bank_name_id:1,bank_name:QQQ}
}
```

this bankname data is repeated

Comment: Can you share xml or annotation mapping.

Answer (score 1):

As per you result it show that you have two variables in emp entity one bank and other bankname so please delete bankname variable from emp entity. and then check otherwise share you code here.

Comment: actually it is the table name (bankname) in employee pojo empid ,empname,bank only declared.While Spring is converting to json these details are added

Comment: please share your code of employee pojo i am sure you have declared to variables of type bank one is bank and other is bankname that's why above json is shown in result.